# How can i split a string based on word boundary in R?

Tags: r, regex

How can i split a string based on space/word boundary in R?

```
t = "ID=gene:Bra032485;biotype=protein_coding;description=AT5G40170 (E%3D6e-176) AtRLP54 | AtRLP54 (Receptor Like Protein 54)%3B kinase/ protein binding ;gene_id=Bra032485;logic_name=glean;version=1"
```

I have tried this but it did not worked

```
sub("([A-Za-z1-9]+)+[[:space:]]","\\1",t)
```

The output i want is

```
ID=gene:Bra032485;biotype=protein_coding;description=AT5G40170
```

Comment: What's your desired result?

Comment: You might want to include your desired output as well.

Comment: Try `sub("^([^[:space:]]+).*","\\1",t)`

Comment: Or as suggested in the dupe - `sub( " .*$", "", t)`

Comment: Both `sub("^([^[:space:]]+).*","\\1",t)` and `sub( " .*$", "", t)` works fine